# Google Oauth client was deleted. can I restore a new one?

Tags: wordpress, google-oauth

We running a wordpress website use google oauth for third-party social login.  (via WP Social Login plugin.) 
 Former engineer is leave, and we cannot have past google account credential.
We face a problem shows:

> Error 401 
>   Error: deleted_client 
>   The OAuth client was deleted.

but we can only see old client id and secret from website admin panel.

I wanna to know,
if we set up a new google oauth application id/secret, will it make user crash from login website?
Or, is it possible for us to restore/retrieve former application ownership and make it live again?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I was working on an Add-On (maybe not completely related to this question but similar). I mistakenly deleted a Client ID that I thought we weren't using.

How I solved it:

- Created a new project in Google Cloud
- Associated the Apps Script project (Add-on) to this new Google Cloud project
- Then I re-associated the App Script project with my previous Google Cloud project
- The previous step will re-compile, create and associate the Client ID to the App Script project. It will contain all settings from the Client ID manually created and associated with your project in the code.

Maybe this will give some light to anyone having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here use this link:

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en

You have to reach google and they will help you out, this is the only solution you can do.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the simplest/only path (though certainly not ideal) ended up being to create a new Firebase project and start using that.

This of course can be problematic if you have a lot of data to move and/or a nontrivial data schema -  say, with nested collections. For me, it was worth the effort to get unblocked from Sign-In suddenly failing to work.

... ah, OAuth fun

=======

If you are trying to make the new Client ID work .. though it's not a total solution, but after searching for a while, found this config option in Firebase console - where you enable Google Sign In.

So if you generate a new OAuth Client ID, update the ID & secret there.

After I did this, it went from a `401` error to a `400` mis_direct , which I think was step in the right direction.

[image]